# Top-level control cannot be added to a control

Tags: c#, winforms

How to Load other Form inside panel in a primary form.

i was trying something like

```
private void frmInitialEntryBooks_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmSujbect objForm = new frmSujbect();
    pnl.Controls.Add(objForm);
    objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    objForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    objForm.Show();
}
```

but it throw exception `Top-level control cannot be added to a control` at line `pnl.Controls.Add(objForm);`

Comment: You must use MDI. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you adding form to the panel

Comment: ya i am adding form to a panel

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Just set toplevel to false?

Comment: NO this is not MDI.... i want to display form inside a panel control

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use this:

```
private void frmInitialEntryBooks_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmSujbect objForm = new frmSujbect();
    objForm.TopLevel = false;
    pnl.Controls.Add(objForm);
    objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    objForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    objForm.Show();
}
```

You are missing `objForm.TopLevel = false;`

Comment: Is there a way to set the opacity of the form that is inside the panel

Answer (score 4):

Set `TopLevel = False` in `frmsubject` then try

```
frmSujbect objForm = new frmSujbect();
pnl.Controls.Add(objForm);
objForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

Method:

```cs
private void PopulateFormIntoTab(Form form)
{
    TabPage page = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    form.TopLevel = false;
    form.Parent = page;
    form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    form.Show();

    tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.Clear();
    tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.Add(form);
}
```

Initialize the form:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();
    tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Form2"));
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Form3"));
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Form4"));

    PopulateFormIntoTab(new Form2());
}
```

Finally, on selected tab index change:

```cs
private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = null;

    switch (tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            form = new Form3();
            break;
        case 2:
            form = new Form4();
            break;
        default:
            form = new Form2();
            break;
    }

    PopulateFormIntoTab(form);
}
```