# Why I'm getting error when adding dropDownMenu to a windows form in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wizard, windows-forms-core

When I'm trying to add a drop-down menu to my form in a wizard, it gives following error.

[image]

Here are the code lines I have written for drop-down menu.

```
dropDownMenu1 = new ToolStripDropDownMenu();
dropDownMenu1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 45);
dropDownMenu1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
this.Controls.Add(dropDownMenu1);
```

**Update**

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821528/top-level-control-cannot-be-added-to-a-control) didn't fix my problem. I have used following code already. But still gives the same error.

```
UserInputForm inputForm= new UserInputForm();
inputForm.TopLevel = false;
inputForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top-level control cannot be added to a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821528/top-level-control-cannot-be-added-to-a-control)

Comment: (hint: it is generally a good idea to _google your error message_. in almost all cases, you're not the first to have a specific problem)

Comment: inputForm.TopLevel = false; I used this but it still shows the error.

Comment: try `dropDownMenu1.TopLevel = false;`

Comment: Tried it. Then there's no error but the drop-down menu is not visible in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of your code,you also have to set Items for dropDownMenu1 and set it to display after you set **dropDownMenu1.TopLevel = false;**. You could try to refer to the following code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    ToolStripDropDownMenu dropDownMenu1 = null;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      dropDownMenu1 = new ToolStripDropDownMenu();
      dropDownMenu1.Items.Add("item1");
      dropDownMenu1.Items.Add("item2");
      dropDownMenu1.Items.Add("item3");
      dropDownMenu1.Location = new Point(90, 45); 
      dropDownMenu1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
      dropDownMenu1.TopLevel = false;
      this.Controls.Add(dropDownMenu1);
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
      {
        //_formContextMenu or this.contextMenuStrip1
        dropDownMenu1.Visible = true;
        dropDownMenu1.Close();
      }
      base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }
    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      dropDownMenu1.Show(e.Location);
    }
  }
```

The result:
[image]

If there is not specific goal for using **ToolStripDropDownMenu** you can also use **ContextMenuStrip** component and Set **ContextMenuStrip** property of form. This way you don't need to write code to show context menu.

For more usage methods of ToolStripDropDownMenu, you can refer to [ToolStripDropDownMenu Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownmenu?view=net-5.0#examples) and [ToolStripDropDown Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown?view=net-5.0).